# Creating a partial index on non-default values and searching all rows in that index in PSQL

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-performance

If I have a table where 99% of rows with column x has a default value and want to search for a specific value in that column, will creating a partial index on x provide any improvements?

For example,

```
CREATE INDEX non_empty_name ON stores (foo) WHERE foo != '';
```

Would the following query actually trigger an index-only scan?

```
SELECT id FROM stores WHERE foo = 'Hello';
```

OR

```
SELECT id FROM stores WHERE foo LIKE '%ello';
```

Comment: The [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) will tell you

Answer (score 0):

The second query will never use a B-tree index, but the first query will use your partial index. For such a query, the partial index would be the best one. Its advantages are:

- it is small, hence fast to scan
- inserting a row with an empty `foo` will not have to modify the index

The partial index can also be used for pattern matching, but only if the wildcard is not in the beginning and you add a second `WHERE` condition `AND foo <> ''`.

For a pattern match like in your second query, you'd need a trigram index. That will be quite a bit slower, but it also won't be too large, since most of the rows will only have the single trigram `'   '`.